# LinkedIn messages jumping around (while chatting)

Tags: google-chrome, linkedin

When I am chatting on LinkedIn, the messages jump around all the time. This is extremely annoying.

For example: I type the sentence *"Thank you very much"* in the chat and press enter. I would expect this sentence to be added to the bottom of the conversation - because it is the most recent one.
Unfortunately, it jumps to some position higher up the conversation and gets shifted in there. A little later, it moves back down where it should be.

The messages jumping around is very very annoying. It happens both in the Google Chrome browser and Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the issue is page refresh.  It's not that the actual message is jumping around, but it appears that way because the connection is causing partial refresh and thus your page is not displaying correctly. Eventually the display catches up with your input and it looks "normal".

Do you get the same experience on another computer, or if you use your device in another place (on another network)?  That's where I'd start troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi @GabyWeiss , thank you very much for your reply. I get this behaviour on every device I've used. My personal computer runs Windows 10, has a 4GHz processor and 16GB RAM. My internet connection is also very fast: 190 Mbps download, 24 Mbps upload and 10 ms ping (measured today on speedtest.net).